# Java 8 SE: Bloco Finally de um método está sendo executado antes de entrar no método

Tags: java, eclipse, try-catch, try-finally

Na página 359 do Livro: Java - Como Programar - 10ª Edição. Deitel explica o tratamento da exceções do Java. Ele exemplifica a questão com o seguinte código:

```
public class UsingExceptions {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
         throwException(); 
      } 
      catch (Exception exception) { // exception thrown by throwException
         System.err.println("4 - Exception handled in main");
      } 

      doesNotThrowException();
   }

   // demonstrate try...catch...finally
   public static void throwException() throws Exception {
      try { // throw an exception and immediately catch it
         System.out.println("1 - Method throwException");
         throw new Exception(); // generate exception
      } 
      catch (Exception exception) { // catch exception thrown in try
         System.err.println(
            "2 - Exception handled in method throwException");
         throw exception; // rethrow for further processing

         // code here would not be reached; would cause compilation errors

      } 
      finally { // executes regardless of what occurs in try...catch
         System.err.println("3 - Finally executed in throwException");  
      }                                                             

      // code here would not be reached; would cause compilation errors
   } 

   // demonstrate finally when no exception occurs
   public static void doesNotThrowException() {
      try { // try block does not throw an exception
         System.out.println("5 - Method doesNotThrowException");
      } 
      catch (Exception exception) { // does not execute
         System.err.println(exception);
      }
      finally { // executes regardless of what occurs in try...catch     
         System.err.println("6 - Finally executed in doesNotThrowException");
      }                                                                  
 
      System.out.println("7 - End of method doesNotThrowException");
   } 
}
```

No livro, Deitel concorda comigo dizendo que a sequência lógica deste código é:

```
1 - Method throwException
2 - Exception handled in method throwException
3 - Finally executed in throwException
4 - Exception handled in main
5 - Method doesNotThrowException
6 - Finally executed in doesNotThrowException
7 - End of method doesNotThrowException
```

Porém, ao executar o código descrito no livro no Eclipse, o Java inverte a linha 6 com a 5 e o resultado fica assim:

```
1 - Method throwException
2 - Exception handled in method throwException
3 - Finally executed in throwException
4 - Exception handled in main
6 - Finally executed in doesNotThrowException
5 - Method doesNotThrowException
7 - End of method doesNotThrowException
```

Ou seja, o Java está chamando o bloco `finally` do método `doesNotThrowException` antes de entrar no método. Alguém sabe explicar o porquê?

Comment: O seu console ou até mesmo o sistema operacional pode estar dando prioridades diferentes para `stdout` e `stderr`. Você já tentou substituir as chamadas para `System.err` por `System.out`?

Comment: Está com cara de ser isso mesmo que o @AnthonyAccioly disse. Esse "comportamento-surpresa" de um bloco `finally` ser executado antes do correspondente bloco `try` é uma inversão de um comportamento bem estabelecido que não acontece no Java sob nenhuma hipótese. A execução do `finally` (que só em umas poucas situações muito peculiares deixa de acontecer, como no caso de ser precedida por um `System.exit()` que finalize a JVM de imediato) é sempre, e por definição, posterior à conclusão normal (ou abreviada por lançamento de exceção) do bloco `try`.

Comment: A dica de @Anthony funcionou. Se renomear todas as mensagens para System.err ou System.out funciona. Pesquisando melhor sobre as prioridades de err e out, descobri que este comportamento se deve a um bug do Eclipse que já foi corrigido. Mais detalhes aqui: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=32205. Estou usando o Eclipse Photon de 2018, por isso acontece a inversão.

Answer (score 4):

O que está acontecendo não é que o `finally` está executado antes do `try`, e sim que `System.out` e `System.err` não estão sendo sincronizadas. No caso, enquanto o seu aplicativo está escrevendo primeiro na `System.out`, o resultado de `System.err` está aparecendo primeiro no seu terminal.

Do lado do Java, quando você executa uma aplicação CLI ele tenta encontrar e configurar as saídas para as *streams* padrão `stdout` e `stderr` do ambiente em que a aplicação está rodando.

Enquanto ambos `System.out` and `System.err` fazem *flush* automático de seus respectivos *buffers* a cada quebra de linha, o que acontece depois disso está fora do controle da JVM.

No caso comum, quando você executa sua aplicação em um *shell* interativo, essas *streams* estão conectadas ao terminal de texto no qual o *shell* está rodando. Esses componentes por sua vez interagem direta ou indiretamente com APIs do sistema operacional para exibir o resultado final para o usuário.

Não há nenhuma garantia de sincronização entre `stderr` e `stdout`. Fazer flush da `stdout` antes da `stderr` não é garantia que seu terminal irá exibir o conteúdo da `stdout` primeiro. Esses componentes fora do controle da sua aplicação podem estar usando *buffers* próprios, múltiplas *threads*, APIs ligadas ao *GPU* e vários outros truques para processar e exibir *streams* de forma eficiente. Manter as *streams* sincronizadas pode ser bastante custoso, e, por padrão, boa parte dos ambientes não faz isso.

Para esse tipo de exercício vale a pena usar uma única *stream*. No caso você pode substituir chamadas para `System.err` por `System.out`.

Alternativamente você pode investigar se há alguma forma de configurar seu terminal para sincronizar as *streams*. Por exemplo, o OP mencionou que ele está usando uma versão antiga do Eclipse. Em versões modernas já existe uma opção para sincronizar *streams* conforme [essa resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58044533/664577).

Comment: Acho que é isso mesmo. Imagino que não seja conveniente o Eclipse adotar essa escrita sincronizada como padrão e sim oferecer como configuração opcional porque isso provavelmente impacta performance e você pode estar desenvolvendo uma aplicação em que isso faça diferença, por exemplo uma que tenha muitas threads executando ao mesmo tempo e gerando logs com frequência, e escrevendo todos numa mesma saída (por exemplo, redirecionado os logs de alguma dessas _streams_ para um único arquivo de log) (se bem que não estou muito certo sobre como isso funciona por debaixo dos panos).

Comment: Sim, já sofri com isso no IntelliJ IDEA também. No geral não dá para confiar na ordem de logs em múltiplas *streams*. No caso do OP o bom é que o `try` tem uma relação *happens-before* com `finally`, mas em outros casos (e.g., `System.out` e `System.err` no mesmo bloco), [o modelo de memória do Java](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_memory_model) permite reordenação das operações. Já vi inclusive *stacktraces* embaralhados com outras entradas em logs. No caso de logs uma solução é mandar `stdout` e `stderr` para arquivos diferentes e fazer a junção conforme *timestamps* das entradas.